# Copy populated cells from a different sheet and find first empty row

Tags: excel, vba

OK, I'm pretty new to the VBA thing.  There's a lot of great info on here but I'm having trouble finding something that meets all my needs.
Sheet 2 contains 7 columns of data (can be from 1-1000 lines long).
Sheet 1 is the master list.  I need all populated cells from sheet 2 pasted into sheet 1 at the first empty cell in column B.
The first empty cell is what's throwing me.  I have an ActiveX command button on sheet 1 to populate it from sheet 2.
Here's the code:
Many thanks! - The cell values aren't correct...the sheet I'm copying from contains 7 columns starting at A1, I just haven't gotten to the point of correcting my formula

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet, myOtherSheet As Worksheet, myBook As Workbook 
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set mySheet = myBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myOtherSheet = myBook.Sheets("Dana")

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer 

j = 28 
For i = 5 To 100 
If mySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then 
   myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = mySheet.Cells(i, 1).Value 
   j = j + 1 
End If
Next i
```

Here's an example[small sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wu6fogkee9rbtht/example%20cut%20paste.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Can you share your code so far? It's easier for people to help if they can see that.

Comment: Here's the code to copy/paste:

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myOtherSheet As Worksheet
Dim myBook As Workbook
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set mySheet = myBook.Worksheets(1)
Set myOtherSheet = myBook.Worksheets("Dana")

i = 1

While mySheet.Cells(i, "B") <> ""

i = i + 1

Wend

i = "B" & i

e = mySheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

myOtherSheet.Range("B1:B" & e).Copy
mySheet.Range(i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but where would I put that into my code (which of course isn't original) so that when the button on the first sheet is pressed it does all of this?

Comment: Is there a way to share an example?